# Wordpress: difference between site_id and blog_id?

Tags: database, wordpress, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to get some understanding of how Wordpress works and while inspecting the database I found that, in a multisite installation, there is a table called `wp_site` that seems  always holding a single record with a corresponding `site_id`.
I cannot understand (nor find on internet) what is the use of `site_id` when actually multisites seem to use `wp_blogs` and corresponding `blog_id` for identifying different sites.(http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)

Can someone shed some light on what should be my understanding of `site_id`?

Thanks

Giuseppe

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`site` is a reference to a *network* of `blog`s.  There are efforts under way to allow WordPress to support multiple networks in addition to multiple blogs, but right now that's not a stock feature (which is why the `wp_site` table only contains one value.

The `wp_blogs` table contains all of the blogs for your entire installation, with each identified by the `site` it's associated with.

This gives you a clean separation between networks, and (eventually) you'll be able to have different "groups" of blogs on one WordPress installation behave like distinct multisite installations.